# WAMP can connect to localhost but not 127.0.0.1

Tags: localhost

I'm running WAMP which was working fine the other day. Today I tried connecting to 127.0.0.1 and my browser throws a 404. Both firefox and chrome. My hosts file is correct mapping 127.0.0.1 to localhost.

I can telnet to both the IP and localhost port 80 and see a response from apache.

When I go to localhost I see the WAMP landing page. I can go to localhost/folder and view the applications just fine.

What can be causing the 404's when I go to 127.0.0.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using a named virtual host called "localhost"? If so, you'll need to access it via the name specified in the config file.

Comment: Forgot I had a few virtual hosts along with one named localhost, deleted all the virtual hosts restarted apache and it's working fine. I'm just wondering why it was working before now and stopped